# Flash HTML5 canvas - targeting one MC from another MC on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, canvas

I am experimenting a bit with Html5 canvas in Flash using the codesnippet embedded in the program. But I cant get the mouseover function to work.
I have two MCs on my stage and trying to hide MC2 when mouseover on MC1.... pretty simple I would think. I have this code but its not working, what am I doing wrong?... and what does the variable "freaquency" do, and is it required?

```
var frequency = 3;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);
this.MC1.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler);

function fl_MouseOverHandler()
{
    this.MC2.visible = false;
}
```

Thanks in advanced

Kim

Comment: Have you checked to see if `this.MC1` is not null? Maybe you just need `MC1`

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar issues with Canvas in the past, perhaps some other user will be able to explain the specifics of why it is happening, but I found the solution is generally to define your stage at the top of your code.

```
var mainStage = this;
var frequency = 3;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);
mainStage.MC1.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler);

function fl_MouseOverHandler()
{
    mainStage.MC2.visible = false;
}
```

for more information on what flash Canvas is actually doing I would recommend checking out the EaselJS documentation.
[Link to Description of what enableMouseOver is actually doing.](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Stage.html#method_enableMouseOver)

Comment: Your approach solves the issue (scope), but I pointed to my answer on this question as another solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638757/how-to-target-a-movieclip-with-createjs/33639412#33639412

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, defining the mainstage in the beginning did the job... ;-)

Kim